# How to avoid capcha's when writing python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, search-engine

I am currently trying to make my own web crawler for personal usage. However when I try to access the website through my python script I get forwarded to a webpage asking me to fill in a captcha. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: This is the webpage I am trying to access: (page numbering starts at 1)
url = 'http://www.immoweb.be/nl/zoek/huis/te-koop/brussel?minprice=100000&maxprice=350000&page=1' + str(page)

Comment: The whole purpose of captchas is to prevent what you're trying to do.  If it were easy to circumvent, it wouldn't be a very good captcha.

Comment: @BrenBarn could you inform me about what consequences this would have if someone found out I develop an algorithm to bypass the CAPTCHA?

Comment: You will likely be banned from the site (e.g., by blocking your IP address).  If you try to use the scraped data to make money somehow, you may be sued.

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to spend a few cents per captcha, you could check out [this article by Troy Hunt.](https://www.troyhunt.com/breaking-captcha-with-automated-humans/)  Basically there's a service run out of low-cost markets, that exposes an API whereby you send the captcha you want solved, and a real human will solve it for you and send back the result.  All this for a pretty minuscule fee.

This may or may not be overkill for your needs :)